# Sobolev inequalities for Banach-valued functions

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis

To what extend do the various different *Sobolev inequalites* hold if I replace the usual **target space** $\mathbb R$ by an arbitrary Banach space, the notion of derivative by **Frechét derivative** and the usual real-valued integral by the **Bochner integral** (correspondingly adapting the definition of *weak derivative*) ?

Comment: Typically, Hahn-Banach helps for such generalizations.

Comment: Could you give an example on how one would make use of Hahn-Banach in this situation ? I am frankly quite surprised that one can apply this Theorem here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question you are asking (and a lot of related material) is discussed in great detail in the article "[W. Arendt and M. Kreuter: Mapping theorems for Sobolev spaces of vector-valued functions](https://dx.doi.org/10.4064/sm8757-4-2017)" (to appear in Studia Mathematica; [preprint](https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.06161) available on arXiv). For embedding theorems, see Section 6.